# Simplest possible SVG line drawer

Tags: xml, svg, line

I'm trying to find the simplest possible SVG line drawer. I'm parsing a svg file for lines (or the two x and y coordinates rather), and using them to create walls in a game I'm creating. All I need is the ability to draw straight lines and save it to a svg file. The output should include the two x and Y coordinates defining the line. It would also be best if I were able to set the size of the document to my choosing (generally a map is 5k * 5k px).

What I'm hoping to find is a very simple program where I simply place lines in the editor and save as an SVG (or any format that can define the two x and y coordinates as a line really). I started looking at inkscape and a few others, but it's generally really advanced tools I dont have the time to learn, plus I have no use of 99.99% of the functionality in those tools.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to a program that could fit my need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SVG-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html), it's a browser based simple editor, the link is to the demo site that I think would fit your purpose.

Pick the line tool, draw your lines, click on the SVG button, grab the XML.

[Official site](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) on google code.

Comment: The SVG-edit tool is perfect, thanks a lot for the tips, Joan Charmant! I was sceptical at first as I could not find a "straight line" option, but then I found an option for toggeling snapping, which is almost as good.

Cheers!

Comment: @skakri: You can also hold down SHIFT key while using the line tool, it will snap the line to 45° steps.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is only a XML file with an precise vocabulary. It needs a text file with a root **svg** tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        .... Lines here
</svg:svg>
```

To do a simple line you can define it with the origin (x1,y1) and destination (x2,y2) and the style. The most simple for your needs is specify "stroke"

```
<svg:line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke:black"/>
```

You can do more complex draws with "polygon" or "rect"

It's trivial to create a parser to convert data in a file or a textbox with a line specification to svg

Salut,

Comment: I'm not looking for ways to parse the SVG file, I'm looking for a tool to create one with a paint-style program. A program where I can draw lines, and then save the "painting" to an svg file so that I can import it and use the line coordinates to create walls in my game.

Inkscape works for this, but it's horribly advanced,. Im looking for something closer to windows paint, that allows svg export.

Comment: I know you said that you don't want to learn InkScape, but it really isn't as hard as it may seem at first. The trick for me was to define the document properties first, eg. 640x480. Draw a line, and then save it as an *optimised* SVG. And then just look at the xml. Position the lines beginning at zero x,y - for the simplest output. Use the snap to grid feature. Just learn a bit at a time, and you'll be an expert in no time.